# method overriding virtual or not

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions

What is the difference between:

a)

```
class base{
   int a;
public:
   virtual int function();
}; 
class derived : public base{
   int b;
public:
   int function();
};
```

b)

```
class base{
   int a;
public:
   int function();
};    
class derived : public base{
   int b;
public:
   int function();
};
```

Why would you use (a) and why would you use (b)?

Is (b) a kind of polymorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) overrides the method in the base class. b) hides it. b) is not polymorphism.

Here's a useful link: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Some people will claim that, when used in templates, `b` can be called static polymorphism...

Answer (score 1):

First is **overidding** while second is **method hiding**.

First is used for dynamic dispatch and dynamic polymorphism. i.e: To call appropriate method depending on actual type of the object at run-time.

Second is used for method hiding.
Good Read:
[What's the meaning of, Warning: Derived::f(char) hides Base::f(double)?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)